# opentbs merge 2 rows in Word document table simultaneously

Tags: php, ms-word, opentbs

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve: 
[image]

Here is what my template looks like:
[image]

And here is my end result:
[image]

I believe it is because I have defined block as w:tr, which refers to a single row only. Is there a way to tell opentbs that the block consists of 2 rows? Thanks.

Comment: Quick fix, I bodged something like this into my project using nested tables, so then you can declare your block as `w:table` instead. I won't answer properly though, as I'm sure someone can come out with a better answer!

Comment: Have you seen this example using `headergrp`? http://www.tinybutstrong.com/examples.php?e=grouping&m=result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to define a block on several rows.
Please note that it is different from a header block upon several detail rows.

A block on tow rows:

```
[al.companyName;block=w:tr+w:tr]
Further detail: [al.detail]
```

or better:

```
[al.companyName;block=tbs:row+tbs:row]
Further detail: [al.detail]
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a lifesaver, almost 2 years after.